# Limit output in pine script, solutions?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I created an indicator in pinescript, the indicator is quite complex. Unfortunately I've reached the limit of 64 outputs, but I really need to add the ability for the user to change color to a plot.
Is there a way around this limit, at least color-wise?

```
plotshape(shortpullbacksignal, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, offset=0, size=size.small,show_last = 3,editable = false)
plotshape(longpullbacksignal, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, offset=0, size=size.small,show_last = 3,editable = false)
```

if I add the color variable to one of the two plots, I go back to the limit and it works, but if I add it to both, I exceed the limit reaching 65.

I tried to see if I could strip something from the code, but it's essential that each element has a changeable or non-constant color. I don't know how to reduce the number of outputs or work around this.

Comment: Each plot consumes 1 _slot_, if the same plot uses a _series_ color instead of a _constant_, it will consume an extra _slot_. There is no way to avoid this limitation.

Comment: And this also applies to color variables that can be selected by the user?

Comment: If it's an `input.color()` - yes, it will take one extra _slot_ too. However, if you provide the plot with a _constant_ color and your script is not using _series colors_ for plots, you can still select another one from the "Style" tab ;) hope this helps.

Comment: In the example I posted they are constant colors, but equally it doesn't give me the possibility to modify the colour from the style options, only the shape :(

Comment: The color pickers will be hidden for _ALL_ plots from the style tab if at least 1 plot in the script is using _series_ color. If ALL plots are using _constant_ colors - color pickers will be available in the style tab.

Comment: Ah ok, in my case then there's nothing to do, being a very complex indicator I use many series colors. Anyway, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can group the plotshape with triangleup
Something like that:

```
triangledown = shortpullbacksignal or shortCondition2 or shortCondition3
plotshape(
  triangledown,
  title      = 'triangledown',
  style      = shape.triangledown,
  location   = location.absolute,
  color      = color.new(color.red, 0))

triangleup   = longpullbacksignal or longCondition2 or longCondition3
plotshape(
  triangleup,
  title      = 'triangleup',
  style      = shape.triangleup,
  location   = location.belowbar,
  color      = color.new(color.green, 0))
```

In this example, with 2 plotshape cover 6 conditions
The bad thing is that you can't identify them
You will not know when it is "ShortPullbacksignal" or "Shortcondition2" or "Shortcondition3"
only see "triangledown"